# Getting InnerHTML of Span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to get the inside text of the following HTML because I want to change the text of that label to be the file input. I am having trouble getting the selected file name and replacing the text of the label with it. I am new to web developing and I am struggling with this task. I would appreciate some help of how to achieve this:

```
 <input type="file" class="inputfile" name="state-resale-certification" id="state-resale-certification" <?php if ($error_occurred == true) {if (array_key_exists('customer-type', $_POST)) { if ($_POST["customer-type"] == "existing") {echo "CHECKED";} }} ?> />
 <label for="state-resale-certification"> <span><i class="fas fa-upload"></i>Upload Sales Certificate</span></label>

 $("body").on( "change", "#state-resale-certification", function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var lbltext = document.getElementById("state-resale-certification").nextElementSibling.childNodes[1].innerHTML;

    alert(lbltext);

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `querySelector` to easily get the span

update to comment:

you can use innerHTML to re-add the icon like so

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" class="inputfile" name="state-resale-certification" id="state-resale-certification"/>
 <label for="state-resale-certification" id="unique-id-so-we-can-point-it-easier"> <span><i class="fas fa-upload"></i>Upload Sales Certificate</span></label>

<script>
$("#state-resale-certification").on("change", function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    
    // save the label element
    var lbl = document.querySelector("label#unique-id-so-we-can-point-it-easier > span");
    // get its text only
    var lbltext = lbl.innerText;
    // get its HTML code
    var lblhtml = lbl.innerHTML;

    // show the text
    console.log(lbltext);
    // show the HTML
    console.log(lblhtml);
    
    
    
    // if we want to replace the label with file name
    
    // 1st, get the file data, since no multiple file allowed, just get the first file
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    
    // then change the label with file name
    lbl.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-upload"></i>' + file.name;
    // you can also use innerHTML if you need to pass HTML code
  });
</script>
```

or just add another `<span>` in the html, and then directly use `querySelector` to point the new `<span>`, like so

```
<input type="file" class="inputfile" name="state-resale-certification" id="state-resale-certification"/>
<label for="state-resale-certification">
   <span>
     <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
     <span id="unique-id-so-we-can-point-it-easier">Upload Sales Certificate</span>
   </span>
</label>
```

Comment: This solution was clean and clear. One thing that this code does though is remove the fa icon in the <i> element which i was trying to avoid. Is there a way around that happening? Thanks for walking through the code with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `innerText`?

```js
var lbltext = document.getElementById("state-resale-certification").nextElementSibling.childNodes[1].innerText
```